Are there good practices or even conventions to store LLM prompts I use while coding?
I sometimes use some language model assistance (e.g., GPT-4o) while coding. I'd like to save somewhere the prompts and language model versions I used. Are there good practices or even conventions to store LLM prompts I use while coding for a project?

Answering comments:
I use prompts that generate new code, e.g. a function to restructure some JSON object or to parse some text file. I'd like save these prompts and LLM versions to remember what kind of prompts and which LLMs worked well, as I may have similar needs in the future.

I don't think there are any general practices here. Fundamentally, this question is opinion-based, and will likely get closed fairly quickly. Although it feels similar in spirit to this question: Best practices for sharing tiny snippets of code across projects. That being said, it's an older question that would likely be closed as opinion-based today.

Can you [edit] your question to include information about the kinds of prompts you are using? Why do you want to save these prompts and LLM versions? Do you expect to use those prompts again in the future?

This has perked my interest because programmers have been dealing with code snippets for ages, but LLM prompts are a new thing. The LLM prompts can lead to code snippets, so this is a new perspective on an old problem. I would just like to see it rephrased so the community can respond with something more objective than personal opinions.

@GregBurghardt Thanks, info added in the question.

That is good information, but I just don't think it moves the question beyond opinion-based answers yet.

@GregBurghardt In what way is the proper use of LLM systems more opinion-based than the proper use of the fantastically complex systems that modern programming languages constitute? Software engineering is all about non-obvious useful knowledge gained from experienced practitioners.

It's not the user of an LLM, here. It's the request for ways to organize prompts for future use. There are a zillion ways to do this with no clear way that is better than the others.

@KilianFoth, I voted to reopen. I've gone back and forth about this question. I'm curious.

What's the proper to phrase a question pertaining to good practices?

The comments on this question tend to indicate that there are no good practices or conventions for storing LLM prompts. Any places to store texts should suffice, and I'd recommending saving the LLM version (to make more reproducible) and if possible, the link to the LLM chat (e.g., to be able to continue the chat if needs be).
